# Copy / paste within for cycle

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy contents from several sheets to a final sheet (let's call it "Report" sheet), where the content of a sheet is copied starting on the first free row after the content of the previous sheet.

I'm using a for cycle to go to each sheet and copy the range that I need and paste it to the Report sheet, but I'm getting:

> Run-time error 1004: "Application-defined or object-defined error"

I already tried changing how to copy/paste the contents, but it still didn't work (`copy and paste special; destination range.value = source range.value; select; ...`).

Do you have an idea of what's going on? 
Thanks in advance for your help!

```
Sub final_data()

    Dim list_end, last_line, h, first_line_range, last_line_range As Integer
    Dim sht_qty As Integer

    h = 1
    i = 2

    list_end = 1

    sht_qty = Application.Sheets.Count


    For h = 1 To sht_qty

        If Workbooks("Testes2").Sheets(h).Name <> "Report" Then

            last_line = Workbooks("Testes2").Sheets(h).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

            first_line_range = list_end + 1
            last_line_range = last_line + list_end - 1

            'the error is on the next line            
            Workbooks("Testes2").Sheets(h).Range("A2:I" & last_line).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Testes2").Sheets("Report").Range("A" & first_line_range & "I" & last_line_range)

        Else
        End If   

    Next h

End Sub
```

Comment: Please read my comment to the answer you received. Using `first_line_range` will cause the data from each source sheet to be pasted over the same range on the destination sheet, again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your destination to this:

```
Destination:=Workbooks("Testes2").Sheets("Report").Range("A" & first_line_range)
```

and that should work

Comment: If it helped You @SSGrace please sign my answer as correct :)

Comment: Your code does fix the `Run-time error 1004:`, but it just paste the range from each source sheet to the same range in the destination sheet, over and over. The `first_line_range` sets the paste range for `Sheets(Report)` to `Range("A2")` for each sheet copied. When pasting from multiple sources you need to reset the last row on the destination sheet. e.g. `Destination:=Workbooks("Testes2").Sheets("Report").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)`.

Comment: @GMalc , thanks, I noticed it as soon as I got rid of the 1004. Already fixed!

Comment: @Teamothy, sorry, this was my first post on stackoverflow. Is it OK now?

Comment: @SSGrace, thank You :) I hope I helped You at your work at least a little bit :)